# Prevent duplication with SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, duplicates, python-2.x

I have the following function:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute="*/3"))
def PeriodicUpdateStockItems():
    #Query to get data from Sims table
    res = Session.query(
        Sims.purchase_order, func.count(Sims.iccid), Sims.create_stamp, Sims.status, Sims.network
    ).filter(
        Sims.stock_sets_id == None
    ).filter(
        Sims.purchase_order != None
    ).group_by(Sims.purchase_order).first()
    print res
    # print Session.query(StockSets.purchase_order).filter(StockSets.purchase_order == res.purchase_order).first()
    if res:
        if not Session.query(StockSets.id).filter(StockSets.purchase_order == res.purchase_order).first() and not Session.query(StockSets.purchase_order).filter(StockSets.purchase_order == res.purchase_order).first():
            print "GOTHERE"
            # Instantiate StockSets table to insert new data 
            newss = StockSets()
            newss.purchase_order = res.purchase_order
            newss.sim_count = res[1]
            newss.create_stamp = res.create_stamp
            newss.status = res.status
            newss.provider_id = res.network
            # Attempt to prevent Duplicate entry from being inserted
            if not Session.query(StockSets.purchase_order).filter(StockSets.purchase_order == newss.purchase_order).first():
                print "GOTHERE-"
                Session.add(newss)
                transaction.commit()
```

This function takes data from one table and inserts it into a new table. I want to prevent duplication of entries.

I have tried adding 2 queries:

```
Session.query(
    StockSets.purchase_order
).filter(
    StockSets.purchase_order == newss.purchase_order
).first()
```

and:

```
Session.query(
    StockSets.purchase_order
).filter(
    StockSets.purchase_order == res.purchase_order
).first()
```

But this has no effect as when I try to print them out it returns `None`
How can I structure a query to prevent duplicate entries?

Comment: You tried adding these 2 queries where? What are you trying to print?

Comment: And why is it a problem that they return `None`? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute="*/5"))
def PeriodicUpdateStockItems():
    """
    A task to add Stock items to the stockstets table and to update the stock_sets_id in the sims table
    """
    res = Session.query(
        Sims.purchase_order, func.count(Sims.iccid), Sims.create_stamp, Sims.status, Sims.network
    ).filter(
        Sims.stock_sets_id == None
    ).filter(
        Sims.purchase_order != None
    ).group_by(Sims.purchase_order).first()
    log.debug(res)
    stock_sets_id = None
    if res:
        stockset = Session.query(
            StockSets.id
        ).filter(
            StockSets.purchase_order == res.purchase_order
        ).first()
        if not stockset:
            stockset = StockSets()
            stockset.purchase_order = res.purchase_order
            stockset.sim_count = res[1]
            stockset.create_stamp = res.create_stamp
            stockset.status = res.status
            stockset.network = res.network
            Session.add(stockset)
            transaction.savepoint()
            stock_sets_id = stockset.id
            log.debug(stock_sets_id)
            transaction.commit()
        else:
            stock_sets_id = stockset.id
            log.debug(stock_sets_id)
        Session.query(
            Sims
        ).filter(
            Sims.purchase_order == res.purchase_order
        ).update(
            {'stock_sets_id': stock_sets_id}
        )
        transaction.commit()
```

I was not using my sqlalchemy queries to the fullest, the first query is actually all I need to check for duplicates:

```
        res = Session.query(
            Sims.purchase_order, func.count(Sims.iccid), Sims.create_stamp, Sims.status, Sims.network
        ).filter(
            Sims.stock_sets_id == None
        ).filter(
            Sims.purchase_order != None
        ).group_by(Sims.purchase_order).first()
```

with this I am preventing Duplication(on insert) and I am updating a table in the same go. in the question I did the update in another function. The purpose of this function is to insert data into one table(no duplicate entries) and update another with the `stock_sets_id`.

@ACV Thanks for your response to this question.

I hope this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to ensure you don't have duplicate entries I think the place to do this is your schema by creating a multi-column uniqueness constraint, not in your insert and updating code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to add those queries to check if the record exist in the db, I was print the queries(`.first()`) to see what value it returns... I would like to keep the schema as is, if possible. even If I make unique keys in the table I would still have to filter them out, otherwise it would return an error(am I wrong?)

Comment: You are correct that having a schema that preserves uniqueness and building unique inserts are separate issues and you have to do both. So I guess I only have 1/2 an answer right now. Could you provide a little more information per my comment on the main question; I'm still unclear on exactly what you're trying to do.